# How is my action get dispatched without me calling dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i've forgot to dispatch my action and just called the function directly and i've noticed that it actually works and i have no idea why.

Can anybody explain to me why/how it works ?

// actions

```
export const resetSearchBar = () => ({
  type: types.RESET_SEARCHBAR,
});
```

// Component

```
fetchProducts = () => {
  const { productName } = this.state;
  const { fetchProductsByName, resetSearchBar } = this.props;

  if (productName) {
    fetchProductsByName(productName);
    return;
  }
  resetSearchBar(); <-- no dispatch ?
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchProductsByName,
  resetSearchBar,
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Comment: [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props. ([connect docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connect))

Comment: Ahhhh that explains everything, Thanks.

Comment: Also see our new React-Redux docs page on [`connect`: Dispatching Actions with `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/using-react-redux/connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapDispatchToProps) for a complete explanation!